# How can I run a react-native frontned and Flask backend offline?

Tags: react-native, flask, progressive-web-apps, offline

I'm creating a react-native frontend and Flask backend application. The communication is done via websocket. The main algorithms are being done on the backend side. I want to be able to use the application when there will be no internet connection.

What would be the most approachable method?

I read about converting the react native app into a progressive web app (PWA) although I have no experience with such thing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.